# How to replace a list inside a multildimensional array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was solving [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72148923/how-to-parse-numpy-array-by-line) on SO and faced a few problems with the methods I was trying.

OP has a list which looks like this,

```
a = [[[100, 90, 80, 255], 
      [80, 10, 10, 255]], 
     [[0, 0, 0, 255],
      [0, 0, 0, 255]]]
```

And they want to replace [0,0,0,255] with [0,0,0,0].

---

For this, I first tried using `np.where(a == [0,0,0,255])` to get all the indices of this list's occurrences but the output was an empty array.

Next, I tried converting the array into a `pandas` dataframe and applied the `replace` function and on it and still the dataframe remained the same.

What are the reasons for `np.where` giving me an empty array and `replace` not changing the dataframe, and how can I fix this?

Comment: For clarity, this is supposed to be 2x2 array...  And you want to replace every occurrence of [0,0,0,255] regardless of where it is??

Comment: @rfportilla Yes

Comment: `where` is only as good as the condition argument, `a == [0,0,0,255]`.  Did you look at that?  You get different results depending whether `a` is really a list (as shown), or a numpy array (as 'described').  You are also being careless in describing the `where` output.  It is a tuple; with at least one array.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah it was my dumb mistake to use `where` on `a` without converting it into a numpy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert `a` to numpy array and use:

```
a = np.array(a)
a[(a == [0, 0, 0, 255]).all(axis=2)] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Output:

```
>>> a
array([[[100,  90,  80, 255],
        [ 80,  10,  10, 255]],

       [[  0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0]]])

>>> a.tolist()
[[[100, 90, 80, 255], [80, 10, 10, 255]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```